# Can't create proper tag?

Tags: support

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/109720/does-the-item-collection-quest-account-for-items-in-previous-volumes-in-hack

I tried creating a tag for [.hack//g.u.] but it didn't come out right. How do we compensate, or what should the tag be?

Answer (score 1):

I've retagged it with [.hack-gu](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.hack-gu).

Comment: In this case, it's killed the trailing period, so perhaps [.hack-gu] is better?

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice.